# Injecting JS file in iFrame via ContentScript in Google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am building an chrome extension where I am injecting my `script.js` file in all the iFrames of the web-page via content script file. Looping through all the iFrames in the web-page and injecting my `script.js file` in the `head` section.

My content script file contains following code:

```
  var $iframe = $('#iframe');
    $iframe.ready(function() {
        $iframe.contents().find("head")
           .append("<script src='chrome://ext3241241234/script.js'/>");
    });
```

My `script.js` file contains following code:

```
var html = "<div id='cksBox'></div>"

$('body').append(html);
```

`script.js` simply insert a `div` element in the `body`. Thus I am expecting all iFrames' body will have this div element in the end.

But this is not happening. Instead of that my main/parent `body` element have this div element rather than inside iFrame body. Say following is web-page where my chrome extension is loaded:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id='cksBox'></div>
    <iframe>
        <html>
            <head>
                <script src='chrome://ext3241241234/script.js'/>
            </head>
            <body/>
        </html>
    <iframe>
</body>
```

I can see that my `script.js` file is loaded inside the iFrame. I tried debugging this, inside script.js file, when I query document, it returns document of parent/main html rather than of iFrame. I do not understand when my `script.js` file is executed its context should be of iframe but it is of document of main/parent web page.

Hope I am clear with my problem here.

Can someone help?

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Could you also provide `manifest.json` and how you inject the scripts?

Comment: I injected via code in content script. Right now I do not have that code. Its simple iFrame.contentDocument.append(...script tag...).

Comment: maybe this is the reason why it keeps the page's scope

Comment: @Savaratkar, how do you create the script tag? I guess you simply used `document.createElement` rather iframe's document?

Comment: @smnbbrv why it keeps the page's scope?

Answer (score 0):

You should directly use `script.js` rather than `chrome-extension` prefix.